# What is the difference between Popup , chromeless window, modal-window, lightbox, hover ad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, accessibility, screen-readers

What is the difference between Popup , chromeless window, modal-window, lightbox, hover ad?

Which is unblockable with default setting on any browser, more accessible with screen reader and even accessible if javascript disabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Popup:** Anything that pops up from your browser. They tend to annoy users, and therefore they are often blocked by the browsers.

**Chromeless Window:** Just another kind of popup window that doesn't show the browser menu or toolbar.

**Modal Window:** The JavaScript `alert()` method is an example of a modal dialog. The users must acknowledge the popup before they can return to operate the parent application.

**Lightbox:**  A modal-dialog JavaScript implementation normally used to display images. Requires JavaScipt and it isn't blocked by browsers unless JavaScript has been disabled.

**Hover Ad:** These are implemented in JavaScript similarly to Lightbox, but are not modal so the users may continue using the parent application. They are used for online advertising solutions and most implementations do not scroll with the web page, and therefore may obscure some of the content. While there is a big chance that Hover Ads may annoy users, they are quite difficult to block.

Comment: http://accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/accessibility-tools/pop-up-window-generator/ this tool three type of popup . What is the difference between these three

Comment: and among all these as i asked in my question which method's content can be accessible even if javascript is disabled?

Comment: @Jitendra: Most probably only the traditional popup would work with JavaScript disabled. However that is the one which is mostly blocked by browsers.

Comment: Popup are opened trhough javascript, it's a 'new browser window' without some toolbars. Aren't they ?
Well, the most efficient way to be accessible, without annoy users should be to use (target=_blank or not, but use a specific class), to open 'popup like', and to parse it with javascript to open it as lightbox if javascript is enabled.

Comment: I think the `target=_blank` links can be classified as popups as well.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the Browser you use, Internet Explorer and Firefox completely blocks the pop-ups with JavaScript Disabled, Google Chrome on the other hand lets Alert Boxes and Announcement boxes still pop-up.You can test it here using your Google Chrome Browser: [Alert Box](http://www.javascriptsandmore.com/javascript-alert-box.html)